# Vue: Showing that the function does not exist when I have defined it the relevant store

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I am currently working on a simple app to store workout routines in Nuxt 3 and Appwrite. The link to the source code is [here](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/workout-buddy).

After logging in and adding in some workouts in the app's UI, whenever I try to call the `deleteWorkout` function, I get an error in the console saying that the function is not defined, whereas I have clearly defined in the `workoutStore`. I can't seem to figure out the reason for the same.
The same can be seen in the given screenshot.
[Console on clicking the delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnRJ9.png)

PS:

1. Most probably the error should be originating from either `/pages/workouts.vue`, `/components/WorkoutDetails.vue` or `/stores/workout.js`.
2. I am using Appwrite to manage the back-end of the web app, and the instructions to setup the same can be found in the README.md. (Though I don't think the error I am facing is related to the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the problem is, you declear your `deleteWorkout()` function outside of the `actions` block in `workout.js` file.

Make sure all your functions in the workout store are inside the actions block. Then it will be accessable from the vue component